# Regular expression problems

Tags: php, regex

I can't get the `preg_match` to find a word anywhere a the string.

I have this:

```
$bad_words = "/(\bsuck\b)|(\bsucks\b)|(\bporn\b)|";
$text = "sucky";

if(preg_match($bad_term_filter, trim($feedback_review_comment)) != 0 )
```

I need to return true but it only returns true if its an exact match, for example if

```
 $text = "suck";
```

that returns true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\b` is the word boundary anchor. It looks like you're trying to find if some word occurs anywhere regardless of the word boundaries, so I think the pattern you want is simply:

```
suck|porn
```

You also do not want the last empty alternate, because that will match everything (all string contains an empty string). There is no need to explicitly look for `sucks`, because it already contains `suck`.

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) and [Character Classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), and [Optional](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html)

Comment: that doesnt fix the issue \b(sucks?|porn)\b

because suckiiiiiii gets by

Comment: @Matt: what about `xsuckx`? Do you want to match that too? If so, just get rid of all `\b` because apparently you don't need it.